# Is it possible to disable an API endpoint based on the server it resides on?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a "ClearAllData" controller endpoint that clears all the data in the SQL database when called. The client requested this for testing purposes but I want to disable this for production. How would I go about doing this? I am using .NET Core 2.2 and C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a resource filter like the following:

```
public class DevelopmentOnlyAttribute : Attribute, IResourceFilter
{
    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {
        var env = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            context.Result = new NotFoundResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, simply decorate the action with this attribute:

```
[DevelopmentOnly]
public IActionResult ClearAllData()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using CORS for this. Allow on this endpoint only specific clients. 
First configure policy to accept specific origins:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowMyOrigin",
            builder => builder.WithOrigins("links to origins"));
    });
}
```

After this you can apply policy to a controller method:

[EnableCors("AllowMyOrigin")]